# Twitter Bootstrap Timepicker Issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I am trying to get the Twitter Bootstrap timepicker to work. My code is below:

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
    // defaultTime: 'current',
    defaultTime: $(this).val(),
    minuteStep: 1,
    disableFocus: true,
    template: 'dropdown'
});
```

The default time is displaying properly from the database, but when I click on the field to try to change the time the timepicker is blank. If I try to move the hour or minute inputs they display "NaN". The AM/PM input displays properly once moved. Is there a setting I need to adjust to get this working? Thanks!

Comment: what is `$(this).val()`

Comment: The value of the field with class="timepicker"

Answer (score 1):

Try this: **defaultTime: false,**

```
$('#time_app').timepicker({
    defaultTime: false,
    minuteStep: 30,
    showInputs: false,
    disableFocus: true,
    modalBackdrop: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `value` in `defaultTime` and assign `value` to `input` and it will work

```
<input class="timepicker" type="text" class="input-small" value="00:00">
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.timepicker').timepicker({
       defaultTime: 'value',
       minuteStep: 1,
       disableFocus: true,
       template: 'dropdown'
   });
});
```

Comment: When I do that and refresh the page, "NaN:NaN undefined" is what is shown in the field.

Comment: Still does the same thing. Wasn't 'value' deprecated? I also tried it using $(this).val() just in case and it still doesn't work.

Comment: change like this and see if it works `defaultTime: '00:00:00'` or `defaultTime: '00:00'`

Comment: When I do that is says 00:00 Undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can try to update the default time in the input field

```
<input id="timepicker1" type="text" class="input-small" value="00:00 AM"/>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/R9ChY/3/)

Comment: I am pulling the value from my database though. I need it to display the value that is stored.

Comment: how are you fetching the value?

Comment: With PHP and then echoing it out as so... value="<?php echo $album['album_time']; ?>". It displays the time as 06:00 PM so it is saved as a VARCHAR(10) in the database. I do not need to do searches based on it so that's why I stored it like that.

Comment: `<input type="text" name="time" id="time" class='timepicker' value="<?php echo $album['album_time']; ?>">`

Comment: Great, I have no idea then.

Comment: can you share the generated html from the browser source

Comment: It's too long, can I email it to you?